# why unable to get alert on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody tell why in my given code I am unable to get alert? Why is `clicked` always false even after my button gets clicked?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    $(document).on('click', '#submit-catalog', function() {
        var clicked = true;
    });
    if(clicked){ // never get executed
        alert("button clicked")
        //i am executing some function only if that button clicked
    }
});
```

Comment: Any errors in your console when clicking?

Comment: Don't use `var` again in the event handler

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs that's also a problem, but not the only problem

Comment: and that's why it's a good comment, but not a good answer

Answer (score 1):

because you created a new variable with another scope inside of your eventhandler
remove the var before it so you set your variable in the document ready function.
Also your queue will handle the if before you can trigger the onclick event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#submit-catalog', function() {
        alert("button clicked")
    });
});
```

Now each time your button fires the onclick event it will show the alert window
If you just want to show the alert window once try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    $(document).on('click', '#submit-catalog', function() {
        if(!clicked) {
            clicked = true;
            alert("button clicked")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Even then the alert will only fire once on load of the page.

Comment: True, because clicked will always be true after that. But that wasn´t part of the question.

Comment: Yes, but `clicked` is never used again after that, so the entire point of the `clicked` variable is moot.

Answer (score 1):

Document ready is executed as soon as the the form finishes loading. Your button is not clicked at that point.

You are adding an event handler to the button that will change the value of the clicked variable as soon as the user clicks the button.

All good and well but If you want something to happen on the click of the button (the functionality you mention) you should run this functionality on the click event. Something like that

```
function doWhatIWant(){
    alert("button clicked")
    //i am executing some function only if that button clicked
}
```

and change your event handler like that

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit-catalog', function() {
    clicked = true;
    doWhatIWant();
    // Or just add your functionality here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not wait for the click listener to be executed before going into the `if`-block.

The variable never gets set to any other value before it's checked.

You also have some syntax errors in your code pointed out by @BraveButter's answer.

If you want to alert once the element has been clicked use this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#submit-catalog', function() {
        alert("button clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: you have a scoping error here. you are creating two different clicked vars here...

Comment: @Luke you're totally right, I left that in there by accident

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your `if` statement is outside the evaluation of the `onClick` function, thus, your `if` is never evaluated.
also you are doing `var clicked = true` inside the `function`.

here you have a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clicked = false;
  $(document).on('click', '#submit-catalog', function() {
    clicked = true;
    if (clicked) {
      alert("button clicked")
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='submit-catalog'> clickme </button>
```

check that if you change the value of `clicked`, as soon as you enter to the `document`, it will trigger an alert. this is because the `if` is evaluated as soon as you enter.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clicked = true;
  $(document).on('click', '#submit-catalog', function() {
    //you call this when you click the button.
  });
  if(clicked){ // never get executed
      alert("button clicked")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just cancel default submit action, set clicked to true and call a function to alert and submit form

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var clicked=false;
        $(document).on('click', '#submit-catalog', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            clicked=true;
            click();

        });

        function click(){
            alert("button clicked")
            //submit catalog form
            $('#catalog-form').submit();
        }
    });
```